# Transfering progress to a different account in Realm of the Mad God

Tags: steam, realm-of-the-mad-god

I used to play [realm-of-the-mad-god](/questions/tagged/realm-of-the-mad-god) a long time ago on an old steam account and since then i started playing again.

I'm on a new Steam account now, is there anyway to transfer my progress from the old account and put it on my new steam account?

Answer (score 1):

No, as Deca said to me:

> Hello Mihail, I am very sorry for my late reply. Thank you for
>   contacting us with your transfer request. I am sorry to inform you,
>   but at the moment we do not offer transfers from the RotMG official
>   website to Steam or Kongregate. Our Game Team is working hard on new
>   improvements to Realm and we are definitely considering implementing a
>   way to transfer accounts from www.realmofthemadgod.com to other
>   platforms in the future. I apologize for any inconvenience this may
>   have caused you and appreciate your understanding in the matter. If
>   you have any further questions regarding this ticket, please do not
>   hesitate to ask.